# Why i'm getting expected begin_array but was String

Tags: java, android

This is my json data

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Message": "User Not Found",
    "Customer_Data": "",
    "Customer_Device": "",
    "Customer_Event": "",
    "All_Event": [
        {
            "event_id": 6,
            "event_name": "Test Event - 1",
            "start_date": "01/06/2019",
            "end_date": "01/06/2019",
            "address_1": "Mumbai",
            "address_2": "Mumbai",
            "location_link": "https://goo.gl/maps/vTia6DQxwmiA5kvz6",
            "pincode": 400060,
            "state_id": 10,
            "city_id": 355,
            "sechudel": "Test",
            "itinerary": "Test",
            "edate": "2019-05-09T17:00:05.95592",
            "eventimg": "http://zaidicorp.in/login/ProcessImage/636935218388448729.png"
        }
    ],
    "Status": 1,
    "Currentdate": "5/16/2019 11:40:54 AM"
}
```

this is my pojo file

```
package mytraining.com.mytraining.Pojo;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class OtpCheck implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("Success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("Message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("Customer_Data")
    @Expose
    private List<CustomerData> customerData;
    @SerializedName("Customer_Device")
    @Expose
    private List<CustomerDevice> customerDevice;
    @SerializedName("Customer_Event")
    @Expose
    private List<CustomerEvent> customerEvent;
    @SerializedName("Event")
    @Expose
    private List<EventDetail> eventDetails;
    @SerializedName("Status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;
    @SerializedName("Currentdate")
    @Expose
    private String currentdate;

    public List<EventDetail> getEventDetails() {
        return eventDetails;
    }

    public void setEventDetails(List<EventDetail> eventDetails) {
        this.eventDetails = eventDetails;
    }

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<CustomerData> getCustomerData() {
        return customerData;
    }

    public void setCustomerData(List<CustomerData> customerData) {
        this.customerData = customerData;
    }

    public List<CustomerDevice> getCustomerDevice() {
        return customerDevice;
    }

    public void setCustomerDevice(List<CustomerDevice> customerDevice) {
        this.customerDevice = customerDevice;
    }

    public List<CustomerEvent> getCustomerEvent() {
        return customerEvent;
    }

    public void setCustomerEvent(List<CustomerEvent> customerEvent) {
        this.customerEvent = customerEvent;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCurrentdate() {
        return currentdate;
    }

    public void setCurrentdate(String currentdate) {
        this.currentdate = currentdate;
    }


    /**
     * Inner Class For Customer Data
     */
    public static class CustomerData implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("cust_id")
        @Expose
        private Integer custId;
        @SerializedName("cust_email")
        @Expose
        private String custEmail;
        @SerializedName("customername")
        @Expose
        private String customername;
        @SerializedName("personalcontact")
        @Expose
        private String personalcontact;

        public Integer getCustId() {
            return custId;
        }

        public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
            this.custId = custId;
        }

        public String getCustEmail() {
            return custEmail;
        }

        public void setCustEmail(String custEmail) {
            this.custEmail = custEmail;
        }

        public String getCustomername() {
            return customername;
        }

        public void setCustomername(String customername) {
            this.customername = customername;
        }

        public String getPersonalcontact() {
            return personalcontact;
        }

        public void setPersonalcontact(String personalcontact) {
            this.personalcontact = personalcontact;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Inner Class For Customer Device
     */
    public static class CustomerDevice implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("cust_id")
        @Expose
        private Integer custId;
        @SerializedName("Cust_device")
        @Expose
        private String custDevice;
        @SerializedName("bg_device_Brand")
        @Expose
        private String bgDeviceBrand;
        @SerializedName("bg_device_model")
        @Expose
        private String bgDeviceModel;
        @SerializedName("android_ver")
        @Expose
        private String androidVer;
        @SerializedName("device_mac")
        @Expose
        private String deviceMac;
        @SerializedName("opt")
        @Expose
        private Object opt;

        public Integer getCustId() {
            return custId;
        }

        public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
            this.custId = custId;
        }

        public String getCustDevice() {
            return custDevice;
        }

        public void setCustDevice(String custDevice) {
            this.custDevice = custDevice;
        }

        public String getBgDeviceBrand() {
            return bgDeviceBrand;
        }

        public void setBgDeviceBrand(String bgDeviceBrand) {
            this.bgDeviceBrand = bgDeviceBrand;
        }

        public String getBgDeviceModel() {
            return bgDeviceModel;
        }

        public void setBgDeviceModel(String bgDeviceModel) {
            this.bgDeviceModel = bgDeviceModel;
        }

        public String getAndroidVer() {
            return androidVer;
        }

        public void setAndroidVer(String androidVer) {
            this.androidVer = androidVer;
        }

        public String getDeviceMac() {
            return deviceMac;
        }

        public void setDeviceMac(String deviceMac) {
            this.deviceMac = deviceMac;
        }

        public Object getOpt() {
            return opt;
        }

        public void setOpt(Object opt) {
            this.opt = opt;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inner Class For Customer Event
     */
    public static class CustomerEvent implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("ticket_no")
        @Expose
        private String ticketNo;
        @SerializedName("seat_no")
        @Expose
        private String seatNo;
        @SerializedName("event_name")
        @Expose
        private String eventName;
        @SerializedName("start_date")
        @Expose
        private String startDate;
        @SerializedName("end_date")
        @Expose
        private String endDate;
        @SerializedName("location_link")
        @Expose
        private String locationLink;
        @SerializedName("edate")
        @Expose
        private String edate;

        public String getTicketNo() {
            return ticketNo;
        }

        public void setTicketNo(String ticketNo) {
            this.ticketNo = ticketNo;
        }

        public String getSeatNo() {
            return seatNo;
        }

        public void setSeatNo(String seatNo) {
            this.seatNo = seatNo;
        }

        public String getEventName() {
            return eventName;
        }

        public void setEventName(String eventName) {
            this.eventName = eventName;
        }

        public String getStartDate() {
            return startDate;
        }

        public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        public String getEndDate() {
            return endDate;
        }

        public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }

        public String getLocationLink() {
            return locationLink;
        }

        public void setLocationLink(String locationLink) {
            this.locationLink = locationLink;
        }

        public String getEdate() {
            return edate;
        }

        public void setEdate(String edate) {
            this.edate = edate;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inner Class For Event Detail
     */
    public static class EventDetail implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("event_id")
        @Expose
        private Integer eventId;
        @SerializedName("event_name")
        @Expose
        private String eventName;
        @SerializedName("start_date")
        @Expose
        private String startDate;
        @SerializedName("end_date")
        @Expose
        private String endDate;
        @SerializedName("address_1")
        @Expose
        private String address1;
        @SerializedName("address_2")
        @Expose
        private String address2;
        @SerializedName("location_link")
        @Expose
        private String locationLink;
        @SerializedName("pincode")
        @Expose
        private Integer pincode;
        @SerializedName("state_id")
        @Expose
        private Integer stateId;
        @SerializedName("city_id")
        @Expose
        private Integer cityId;
        @SerializedName("sechudel")
        @Expose
        private String sechudel;
        @SerializedName("itinerary")
        @Expose
        private String itinerary;
        @SerializedName("edate")
        @Expose
        private String edate;
        @SerializedName("eventimg")
        @Expose
        private String eventimg;

        public Integer getEventId() {
            return eventId;
        }

        public void setEventId(Integer eventId) {
            this.eventId = eventId;
        }

        public String getEventName() {
            return eventName;
        }

        public void setEventName(String eventName) {
            this.eventName = eventName;
        }

        public String getStartDate() {
            return startDate;
        }

        public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        public String getEndDate() {
            return endDate;
        }

        public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }

        public String getAddress1() {
            return address1;
        }

        public void setAddress1(String address1) {
            this.address1 = address1;
        }

        public String getAddress2() {
            return address2;
        }

        public void setAddress2(String address2) {
            this.address2 = address2;
        }

        public String getLocationLink() {
            return locationLink;
        }

        public void setLocationLink(String locationLink) {
            this.locationLink = locationLink;
        }

        public Integer getPincode() {
            return pincode;
        }

        public void setPincode(Integer pincode) {
            this.pincode = pincode;
        }

        public Integer getStateId() {
            return stateId;
        }

        public void setStateId(Integer stateId) {
            this.stateId = stateId;
        }

        public Integer getCityId() {
            return cityId;
        }

        public void setCityId(Integer cityId) {
            this.cityId = cityId;
        }

        public String getSechudel() {
            return sechudel;
        }

        public void setSechudel(String sechudel) {
            this.sechudel = sechudel;
        }

        public String getItinerary() {
            return itinerary;
        }

        public void setItinerary(String itinerary) {
            this.itinerary = itinerary;
        }

        public String getEdate() {
            return edate;
        }

        public void setEdate(String edate) {
            this.edate = edate;
        }

        public String getEventimg() {
            return eventimg;
        }

        public void setEventimg(String eventimg) {
            this.eventimg = eventimg;
        }


    }
}
```

this my is java calling class

```
 private void eventDetial(Map<String, String> map) {

        Call<OtpCheck> call = apiInterface.eventShow(map);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<OtpCheck>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OtpCheck> call, Response<OtpCheck> response) {
                List<OtpCheck.EventDetail> data = response.body().getEventDetails();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    image = data.get(i).getEventimg();
                    Log.i("Data", "data");
                    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image).into(imageView);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<OtpCheck> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried multiple ways from StackOverflow but still not getting error

expected begin_array but was String

Comment: In which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: make sure that the JSON you are getting matches the JSON you expect. You are probably getting not the JSON string in response

Answer (score 2):

Firstly got Error from below field, this 3 field is String but you set ArrayList. But it will be String. Like below.
"Customer_Data": "",
    "Customer_Device": "",
    "Customer_Event": "",

```
 @SerializedName("Customer_Data")
@Expose
private String customerData;
@SerializedName("Customer_Device")
@Expose
private String customerDevice;
@SerializedName("Customer_Event")
@Expose
private String customerEvent;
```

Also, Have no any event field. so need change from

```
@SerializedName("Event")
@Expose
private List<EventDetail> eventDetails;
```

To

```
@SerializedName("All_Event")
@Expose
private List<EventDetail> eventDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your @SerializedName:

```
@SerializedName("Event")
@Expose
private List<EventDetail> eventDetails;
```

The tag SerializedName must have the name of the element of the json. Then you must changue it for:

```
@SerializedName("All_Event")
@Expose
private List<EventDetail> eventDetails;
```